# How to get clang-format to break on << and >>

Tags: c++, clang-format

How can I get clang-format to break on '<<' and '>>' operators?

I tried setting BreakBeforeBinaryOperators to All, but this does not seem to make any difference here.

I would like my code to be formatted like this:

```
in >> a
   >> b
   >> c;
```

instead of

```
in >> a >> b >> c;
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to break on *every* `<<` or `>>` operator?  Including bit-shifting ones? :)

Comment: `BreakBeforeBinaryOperators` only determines whether to break the line before or after a binary relation, it doesn't enable linebreaking at *every* binary operator.

Comment: Yes, I don't use bit-shifting but use a lot of stream io.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if it doesn't enforce the breaking, but at the moment it always combines it on one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you need two style settings:

```
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All
ColumnLimit: 0
```

Or, set the style to the pre-defined `WebKit` style, which will set those two style settings for you.

The [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) says:

> A column limit of 0 means that there is no column limit. In this case,
> clang-format will respect the input’s line breaking decisions within
> statements unless they contradict other rules.

This isn't a great solution, for several reasons:

- As the documentation says, clang-format will respect the line breaks that you started with. But it won't add line breaks if they're not already there. So a line `in >> a >> b >> c;` will not get broken into separate lines.
- The output does not line up the `>>` of the first line with the `>>` of the subsequent lines. It is simply indented by the usual continued-line amount. For example, if your normal indentation is 4, you will get:

  ```
  in >> a
      >> b
      >> c;
  ```

  This is actually a little strange, because if the operator was `<<`, clang-format would line up all three of the operators.
- You may, and probably do, want `ColumnLimit` set to something else like 80 so that other lines get broken in reasonable places.

But this seems to be the best that can be done with clang-format.

I tested with clang-format 6.0.0, but I believe newer versions will act similarly, and I don't see any new style options which look like they would help.

Comment: This looks like it should help, but sadly doesn't...:  AlignOperands (OperandAlignmentStyle) clang-format 3.5

Answer (score 1):

The only "somehow" way I've found is to add empty comment after each line. And it will looks like this:

```
v << value_1       //
  << value_2       //
  << some_value_3  //
  << last_value_4;
```

Comment: This dose the trick for `if (a && b && c ...)` too